# Persisting PSModulePath across all sessions

Tags: powershell

I have a PSModule that I would like to put in my own PSTools directory instead of the standard powershell reserved directory for PSModule. I used the command

```
$env:PSModulePath += ';c:\MyPSModule'
```

This works but it is only good for my current session and PS seems to have forgotten my settings after a new session is created and I have to set it up again.

How do I persist my $env settings across all powershell sessions and if possible for all users? If possible, I do not want to hack the registry. Just ps command only if this is feasible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$CurrentValue = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("PSModulePath", "Machine")
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("PSModulePath", $CurrentValue + ";C:\MyPSModule", "Machine")
```

> To add a persistent variable by using a script, use the
>   SetEnvironmentVariable method on the Environment class. For example,
>   the above script adds the "C:\MyPSModule" path
>   to the value of the PSModulePath environment variable for the
>   computer. To add the path to the user PSModulePath environment
>   variable, set the target to "User".
>
> - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878326(v=vs.85).aspx